# About reversing the Euclidean Algorithm, Lemma of Bézout

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, euclidean-algorithm

From the book Discrete Mathematics for Computing 2nd Edition in eBook:

[image]

I know how to perform the Euclidean Algorithm and GCM(a,b). I am however, deeply confused by this:

$$1 = 415 - 69(421 - 1 \times 415)$$
$$ = 70 \times 415 - 69 \times 421$$

---

### **How is this expression constructed $70 \times 415 - 69 \times 421$?**

---

N.B. I am still new to this and learning, I am using the following book(s):

```
Discrete Mathematics for Computing / Edition 2
by Peter Grossman [eBook]

Discrete Mathematics for Computing / Edition 3
by Peter Grossman [Physical copy]
```

Comment: Count how many $415$s are in that expression.  (Answer:  $1+69$.)

Comment: $415-69(-1\times415)=(1-(-69))(415)=70\times415$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks. Care to explain? This looks very confusing to me still. **Still confused since I do not see the steps from $1 = 415 - 69(421 - 1 \times 415)$ to $=70  \times 415 - 69 \times 421$?

Comment: It's just algebra:  $x + ax= (1+a)x$.

Comment: @Randall, sure, but this whole expression jumping looks confusing, since we do not solve for anything specific i.e., freeing a variable.

Comment: You combine the $415$ terms and separate them from the $421$ term

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you mean **421 - 415**? Or, like similar take out each other?

Comment: You're just collecting like terms, but the "like terms" are $415$s and $421$s.

Comment: @Randall you mean similar terms negate each other, right?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, so that means, 415 + 415 because there are two terms.

Comment: one of the "$415$" terms is multiplied by $(-69)(-1)$

Comment: By the way, there are a couple more worked examples over at the page on [Bézout's identity on Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/bezouts-identity/) if you want to see this arithmetic in action.

Comment: Imagine if it was $x-69(y-x)$. Can you see how that equals $70x-69y$?

Comment: You do have $1=a-b(c-1\times a)=(b+1)a-bc$

Comment: @Malady Yes, in this context I can, because it doesn't look like the above.

Comment: Since you understand collecting like terms in $x-69(y-x) = 70x-69y$, will you find it more understandable to name all the dividends, divisors and remainders from the beginning? $r_0 = 2093$, $r_1 = 836$, $r_2=421$, ... Then the equations become:
$$\begin{align*}
r_4 &= r_2 - 1r_3 \tag 3\\
r_5 &= r_3 - 69r_4 \tag4\\
&= r_3 - 69(r_2-1r_3)\\
&= 70r_3-69r_2
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @AlixBlaine Okay, that equality is true for all values of $x,y$. Thus it is true when $x=415$, $y=421$. Does that make sense?

Comment: We can just do the following to get to the $70\times415-69\times421$: 
$$415-69(421-1\times415)=415-69(421-415)$$ 
Now don't calculate the $421-415$ just factorize. 
$$415-69(421-415)=415+(-69\times421)+(-69\times -415)=415-69\times421+69\times415=415+69\times415-69\times421$$

Now we have $415+69\times415-69\times421$, in this expression we have one $415$ plus $69$ $415$s. That makes $70$ $415$s. So we have $70\times 415-69\times 421$.

Finally we have $$415-69(421-1\times415)=70\times415-69\times421$$

Comment: Wow. A fifty point bounty for a canonical explanation for a line or two of elementary high school algebra. That should attract lots of identical answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, the calculations from the quotation concern to construct an integer solution $(x,y)$ of the Diophantine equation $2093x+836y=1$. To do this, we apply first the Euclidean algorithm to find the greatest common divisor to numbers $r_1=2093$ and $r_2=836$ and then go backwards. Namely, the Euclidean algorithm yields:

$r_3=421=2093-2\times 836=r_1-2\times r_2$

$r_4=415=836-1\times 421=r_2-1\times r_3$

$r_5=6=421-1\times 415=r_3-1\times r_4$

$r_6=1=415-69\times 6=r_4-69\times r_5$.

Next we go backwards:

$1=r_6=r_4-69\times r_5=415-69\times 6$

$1=r_4-69\times r_5=r_4-69\times (r_3-1\times r_4)=-69\times r_3+70\times r_4=-69\times 421+70\times 415$

$1=-69\times r_3+70\times r_4=-69\times r_3+70\times (r_2-1\times r_3)=70\times r_2-139\times r_3=70\times 836-139\times 421$

$1=70\times r_2-139\times r_3=70\times r_2-139\times (r_1-2\times r_2)=-139\times r_1+348\times r_2=-139\times 2093+348\times 836$

That is we constructed an integer solution $(x,y)=(-139,348)$ of the equation $2093x+836y=1$.

Comment: Hi, I am super confused by $r_n$ in your examples.

Comment: Can you simplify this with those numbers from the book example?

Comment: @AlixBlaine The $r_n$'s are consecutive remainders of the Euclidean algorithm. They are used to indicate what is going on. Yes, we can skip them, but then the calculations will become a distributivity exercise. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "a distributivity exercise"?

Comment: @AlixBlaine A sequence of arithmetic transformations, based on the distributive law, for instance:
$1=415-69\times 6=415-69\times (421-415)=-69\times 421+70\times 415=
-69\times 421+70\times (836-1\times 421)=70\times 836-139\times 421=
70\times 836-139\times (2093-2\times 836)=-139\times 2093+348\times 836.$

I think, this does not explain a lot what is going on and from where we obtained the respective numbers.

Answer (score 3):

> How is this expression constructed $70 \times 415 - 69 \times 421$?

Using colors might be helpful.

$$\begin{align}1& = \color{red}{415} - 69(\color{blue}{421} - 1 \times \color{red}{415})
\\\\&=\color{red}{415} - 69\times \color{blue}{421} +69 \times\color{red}{415}
\\\\&=\color{red}{415}+69 \times \color{red}{415} - 69\times \color{blue}{421}
\\\\&=(1+69)\times \color{red}{415}- 69\times \color{blue}{421}
\\\\&=70 \times \color{red}{415} - 69 \times \color{blue}{421}\end{align}$$

---

To get a solution $(x,y)$ of the equation $\color{purple}{2093}x+\color{orange}{836}y=1$, they started with
$$\color{blue}{421}=\color{purple}{2093}-2\times \color{orange}{836}\tag1$$
$$\color{red}{415}=\color{orange}{836}-1\times \color{blue}{421}\tag2$$
$$\color{green}6=\color{blue}{421}-1\times \color{red}{415}\tag3$$
$$1=\color{red}{415}-69\times \color{green}6\tag4$$

They have
$$\begin{align}1&=\color{red}{415}-69\times \color{green}6
\\\\&=\color{red}{415}-69\times (\color{blue}{421}-1\times \color{red}{415})
\\\\&=70 \times \color{red}{415} - 69 \times \color{blue}{421}
\\\\&=70 \times (\color{orange}{836}-1\times \color{blue}{421})- 69 \times \color{blue}{421}
\\\\&=70\times \color{orange}{836}-139\times \color{blue}{421}
\\\\&=70\times \color{orange}{836}-139\times (\color{purple}{2093}-2\times \color{orange}{836})
\\\\&=\color{purple}{2093}\times (-139)+\color{orange}{836}\times 348\end{align}$$

Therefore, $(x,y)=(-139,348)$ is a solution of the equation $\color{purple}{2093}x+\color{orange}{836}y=1$.

Comment: How do you go from: $= 415 - 69 \times 421 + 69 \times 415$ to $= 415 + 69 \times 415 - 69 \times 421$ and from this to: $= (1 + 69) \times 415 - 69 \times 421$ ? I don't understand the steps and transitions that's happening there!

Comment: @Alix Blaine : Since we have that $A-B+C$ is equal to $A+C-B$, setting $A=415,B=69\times 421$ and $C=69\times 415$ gives $$415−69×421+69×415$$$$=415+69×415−69×421$$ Next, since we have that $E\times D+F\times D-G$ is equal to $(E+F)\times D-G$, setting $D=415,E=1,F=69$ and $G=69\times 421$ gives $$415+69×415−69×421$$$$=1\times 415+69\times 415-69\times 421$$$$=(1+69)\times 415-69\times 421$$

Comment: So you are doing some re-writing?

Comment: Any link where I can learn about this?

Comment: How to you arrive here: $1 \times 415 + 69 \times 415 - 69 \times 421$, I fail to see what happens exactly?

Comment: @Alix Blaine : "you are doing some re-writing?" Yes, I am. "Any link where I can learn about this?" You might want to see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). "How to you arrive here: $1×415+69×415−69×421$" Since we have that $A+B−C$ is equal to $1×A+B−C$ (just rewriting $A$ as $1\times A$), setting $A=415,B=69×415$ and $C=69×421$, we have $$415+69×415−69×421$$
$$=1×415+69×415−69×421$$

Answer (score 2):

You already brought up the Euclidean algorithm.
For $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $\operatorname{gcd}(n,m)=1$ you get from "reversing" the algorithm an expression of $1=an+bm$.

Example:

$\operatorname{gcd}(13,23)=1$.

We have

$23=1\cdot 13+10$

$13=1\cdot 10+3$

$10=3\cdot 3+1$

Now use the last equation to get an expression in $1$ and substitute into the other equations to express this in terms of $23$ and $13$.

So $1=10-3\cdot 3$.

Now $13=1\cdot 10+3\Leftrightarrow 3=13-10$ (we solve for the "remainder" for the substitution)

Now plug this in for $3$.

$1=10-3\cdot (13-10)=10-3\cdot 13+3\cdot 10=4\cdot 10-3\cdot 13$.

Proceed and solve the first equation for $10$.

$10=23-13$.

Plug this in:

$1=4(23-13)-3\cdot 13=4\cdot 23-4\cdot 13-3\cdot 13=4\cdot 23-7\cdot 13$.